# Google Maps - Change all markers size on different zoomlevels - map.data.setStyle

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I try to change the size of my markers on google maps all at once with `map.data.setStyle`. At the moment I have this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

    var size;
    var zoom = map.getZoom();

    if (zoom > 7) {

        console.log("under 7");

        size = new google.maps.Size(50, 50);

        map.data.setStyle(function() {

            return ({
            icon: {
              scaledSize: size,
              size: size
            }

            });

        });


    } else {

        console.log("over 7");

        size = new google.maps.Size(10, 10);

    }});
```

It doesn´t change the markers size. I know how to do it with a loop, but I have around 1000 markers and render them all again on a zoomlevel-change does not seem performant. Another problem is, that I am not allowed to change the icons-picture link, because they are all different, I only need to change the size.

Isn´t there an easy way to change the size of all markers? It seems so obvious, that you would need a tool like this. Regards Sven

Comment: What icons are you trying to scale?  (the default marker can't be scaled).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I would like to resize all markers visible on the map on a zoomevent, without looping through them and without changing the icon. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that ***it is not possible to scale size of default markers***.

Could you please try this sample **[demo](https://jsbin.com/waxubor/edit?html,output)** that I have created? I used:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

and created a new marker once the old marker has been removed whenever the map detects a "**zoom_changed**".

Hope this could be helpful on your use case and happy coding!